# Mouse Overs with Divs

Tags: html, mouseover

I am trying to get this mousever to work, but I seems to be acting very buggy in all browser versions. I have something like this

```
<div id="foo" onMouseOut="makeHidden('foo');"><a href="somelink">Link Text</a></div>
```

I don't want the div to be hidden when the mouse goes over the link, and I assumed it wouldn't because the link is in the div.  How can I get the div to stay visible until the mouse leaves it's boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look in to using jQuery http://jquery.com/
Then you could write something like this:

```
$("#foo").mouseenter( function(){makeHidden('foo');} );
$("#foo").mouseleave( function(){makeVisible('foo');} );
```

Or just cut out the middle man

```
$("#foo").mouseenter( function(){$(this).css("visibility", "hidden");} );
$("#foo").mouseleave( function(){$(this).css("visibility", "visible");} );
```

Comment: Sorry, I read that backwards. The same principle should work, just swap the visibility changes.

Comment: You'll just download the jQuery.js from the site, place it wherever you like and link to it in your file through something like <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script> Then you can place the code above pretty much anywhere because it just acts as an event handler. I would suggest adding it in an external javascript file or in your header. Make sure to it's in side of the $(document).ready section http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I place the call inside of a ready function, and included the library, it still doesn't work :-(

Comment: @MikeC Happy 20th! :)

Answer (score 0):

By using a fancy bubbling trick. See: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/kZcCr/

You want to stop the propagation of the `mouseout` event if it's being applied to an element's children, and you also want to cancel the `mouseout` of the parent if we're moving into one of its children. That can be done using `relatedTarget`, or `toElement` on IE.

Answer (score 0):

actuallly i m not geeting ur point might be this code will help u

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

function abc (mylink){

```
document.getElementById('mylink').style.display = 'none';

}
```

function abcd(mylink){

```
document.getElementById('mylink').style.display = 'block';
```

}